# Add parameter into body with Scribe Library

Tags: android, scribe, oauth-1.0a

I'm developing an Android app and I have integrated Scribe library to make http connection with OAuth1.0 with Magento. My problem is that I need to send a request with a parameter into body but without a key. Now I make login correctly and I have my Token authorized, I get products from server, categories, blah blah... but I cannot make checkout because always I get code "401 Authorization require". I think that the problem could be by the parameter in the body.

**My code:**

```
...
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... json) {
           String result = null;
           org.scribe.model.Response response = null;
           String url = Global.BASE_URL + "cart/1";

           if(Global.TOKEN_AUTHORIZED != null) {
             OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url);
             //I only need insert a json into body without key
             request.addBodyParameter(<I don't need a key>, json[0]);
             Global.OAUTH_SERVICE.signRequest(Global.TOKEN_AUTHORIZED, request);
             response = request.send();
           }

           if(response != null && response.getCode() == 200) {
             result = response.getBody();
           } else {
             result = "ERROR";
           }
           return result;
        }
...
```

How I put only a parameter in the body but without key, value?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. First is necessary to add a Header to say that content of the request is a json
2. To add a single parameter into the body without key, value exists a method called addPayload(String)

Now I get a response with code 200 :)

```
    if(Global.TOKEN_AUTHORIZED != null) {
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addPayload(params[0]);
        Global.OAUTH_SERVICE.signRequest(Global.TOKEN_AUTHORIZED, request);
       response = request.send();
   }
```

I hope to help somebody :)

Comment: I tried using the same code but it is returning response body as null, do you have any idea about solving this?